# How to find first bad number from float

Tags: c

I have this problem : I am entering numbers to float ... I want program to find out, which first number is not from specific interval.
How to do it ? 
Example: Enter input : 5 10 20 30 50 46 . 30 is invalid.
Problem is,that printf is printing me just first number of float,for example: 10 20 30 40 50. 10 is invalid... I expected "30 is invalid" 
Here is the code :

```
while(scanf("%f",&input)!=EOF || input==0){

sum=input+sum;
if (getchar() == '\n') break;
};

for (int i=0;i<14;i++)
{
if(input!=notes[i])
{
    printf("%f is invalid\n",input);
}

}
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Strict comparison operators do not work well with floating point numbers. It's likely `input != <something>` will always be true

Comment: Thanks. May I ask what would you suggest ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't quite understand your question. I've just pointed at some potential pitfall.

Comment: how is the user expected to know what a 'valid' input number sequence consists of?

Answer (score 0):

you can keep this numbers 100,50,20,... in the array and use for loop to check whether some number is equal to any one of them, if so then number is valid, else invalid

Comment: Thanks for reply. So I I made something like this: 

So I have all those numbers in array now. Problem is,that printf is printing me just first number of float,for example: 10 20 30 40 50. 10 is invalid... I expected "30 is invalid"

Comment: Most of those numbers (their integers) will NOT exactly match any  float value.  write them as floats or use 'floor() or ceil() on the input or (better) write the numbers in the array as float values I.E. 100.0f, 50.0f, 20.0f, ...

Answer (score 0):

Well,I found the answer :

```
while(scanf("%f",&input)!=EOF || input!=0)
{
if (input == 0) break;
sum=input+sum;

    if(input!=100 &&input!=50 &&input!=20 &&input!=10 &&input!=5 &&input!=2 &&input!=1 &&input!=0.5 &&input!=0.2 &&input!=0.1 &&input!=0.05 &&input!=0.02 &&input!=0.01)
    {
            if (input ==  (int) input)  
       printf("%.0f is invalid!\n" ,input);
      else printf("%.2f is invalid!\n" ,input);
            exit(1);
    }


     if (getchar() == '\n') break;
};
```

Anyway,thanks for help :)!

Comment: 1) please indent after open brace '{' and unindent after closing brace'}'  2) the use of getchar() is a problem because it consumes the next available character from stdin, which (usually) will be the first character of the next input value.  3) a float value (usually) is not an exact representation of some integer number, (I.E. int 10 is not equal to float 10.0f)  4) float values are written as (for instance) '100.0f'  not '100' <-- that one is a int value, nor '100.0'  <-- that one is a double value.  I.E. a float value must have a decimal point And a trailing 'f'.

Comment: 5) always check the returned value from scanf (and family) to assure the operation was successful.  using: 'while(scanf("%f",&input)!=EOF || input!=0)' as an example, the returned value from scanf() would be 1, because there is one input/conversion specifier in the format string.

Comment: 6) please post compilable code that displays the problem, so we can help you debug the issue.  7) do not use tabs in posted code (nor in your own code) as a tab will insert a different amount of white space, depending on where the tab stops are set or the editor is set for a tab width.